# Why does this algorithm work (where does it come from) for finding the period of a decimal expansion?

Tags: number-theory

For the period of something like $1/d$ where $d$ is a positive integer, I saw an algorithm repeatedly doing:

$$\begin{align*}r &= 1\\
r &= 10r \bmod d \quad\text{ (until } r = 1)
\end{align*}$$

and the number of steps was the period.

Comment: The period is the smallest positive $k$ such that $10^k\equiv 1\pmod{d}$.  Of course we must put restrictions on $d$. Assume that neither $2$ nor $5$ divides $d$.

Comment: It does not work for $d=6$

Comment: Ah yes I had it wrong but it was just long division.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just long division. Once you reach the end you take the remainder over, put a zero next to it and repeat the process, eg:

$$
2/5 = (2.0)/5 = 0.4
$$

So in this case since we are doing $1/d$ we start with one. How many times this process is repeated is just how many times we carried the remainder over which is the length of the decimal.

Comment: Ah you're exactly right.